# Embedding real-time Grafana dashboards in Django web application

Tags: django, grafana

I want to embed a real-time grafana dashboard into my django web application. Currently, I have embedded the individual panels of the dashboard in my django applications using the iframe link that is generated by grafana, but they are just a snapshot of the graph and the individual panels do not scroll automatically to the current time.